# I get the undefined ERROR when I try to get the data using an API from Child to Parent through @ViewChild?

Tags: angular

I have a filter bar and I want to show the jobs number for all category **All Jobs** & **Archived Jobs** in the parenthesis **Exemple:** **All(NumberOfAllJobs)**.
[image]

I get the **data** from **Child Component** and use it on **Parent Component**. In **Child Component** the **data** is coming from an **API**. I tried to use **@ViewChild** but, in console  I get `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'countArchiveJobs' of undefined` and I don't no what to do.

**Child Component TS File:**

```
companyData: any = [];
jobs: any = [];
archivedJobs: any = [];
countArchiveJobs: string;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private companyDataService: CompanyDataService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    // Get data about current user company
    this.companyDataService.getCurrentUserCompany().subscribe(resData => {
        this.companyData = resData;

        // Get all jobs from company
        this.companyDataService.getJobsFromCompany(this.companyData.id).subscribe(jobs => {
            this.jobs = jobs;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.jobs.length; i++) {
                if (this.jobs[i].status === 'Archived') {
                    // Push only the archive jobs
                    this.archivedJobs.push(this.jobs[i]);


                    // Here is the part where I store the number I want to display on parent component
                    this.countArchiveJobs = this.archivedJobs.length;
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

**Parent Component TS File:**

```
@ViewChild(CompanyJobsArchivedComponent, {static: true}) archiveJobs: CompanyJobsArchivedComponent;

getCountAchievesJobs: string;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getCountAchievesJobs = this.archiveJobs.countArchiveJobs;
    console.log(this.getCountAchievesJobs);
}
```

**Parent HTML Template File:**

```
<span>{{getCountAchievesJobs}}</span>


// Here I render the child content
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example?

Comment: Will it be okay if you use `@Output` decorator to pass data from child to parent component?

Answer (score 0):

{ static: true } needs to be set when you want to access the ViewChild in ngOnInit.

{ static: false } can only be accessed in ngAfterViewInit.

You are using archiveJobs in ngAfterViewInit so it will be static: false

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of observable incompleteness.
the observable is not completed when parent component's AfterViewinit gets called.

The best solution is to use Event Emitter in child component

In Child Component

```
@Output() NumberOfJobs = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

After this line

```
this.countArchiveJobs = this.archivedJobs.length;
Add : this.NumberOfJobs.emit(this.countArchiveJobs)
```

In ParentComponent html where child component html is placed

```
<ChildComponent (numberOfJobs)="getNumberofJobs($event)"></ChildComponent>
```

In Parent Component.ts

```
getNumberofJobs(num : number){
// num is the number of jobs
}
```

Comment: Can I use this method on router-outlet?

Comment: not in this structure.

assuming you use <router-outlet> in app.componentwhich is definately parent parent of you component which emits the event in that scenario using Event Emitter in Service is based solution.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Subhojit Khara!
I manage to find an alternative solution for my problem. I restructured my project and I moved all the content in one component. This way was much easier for me to achieve what I wanted.